# Nutrition Facts Detection with OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I would like to detect some nutrition facts on food package with an Android Application, with OpenCV.
So far I managed to do it with one image of a nutrition table, but of course it only works with this one.

The goal is to detect and retrieve the value of Energy, Proteines, and Glucides, for 100g of product. These informations are present in almost every table, that is why I focus only on them for the moment.

So I was wondering if there a good method to do so ? For the moment, I try to detect each block of text, recognise it with Tesseract, and if it fits the word I'm looking for, I get the corresponding column and line in the picture, to finally get the value I want.

Is there any way to track the words straightly, and get the value that fits best in the image (in terms of alignement with the "100g" column).

Typical image : hpics.li/4231f79

Sorry if my problem is not well explained, just ask if something is not clearor if you want me to explain more what I've done for the moment.. Also sorry for my english

Cheers

Comment: Could you show us the image you used? If your method worked for that specific image, why it doesn't work in other images?

Comment: I wish I could upload an image but I don't have enough reputation points..

Comment: It works with this image only because of the process I apply to the image (contours finding, size criteria), but when applied to other images, doesn't work anymore. I'm looking for a "tracking" method, that could automaticaly look for these words. For now, I have to test and analyse each "blob" of the binarized image...

Comment: @zedv here is an example image 
http://hpics.li/4231f79

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ideas:
1. Convert image to HSV color space and look only for black and white regions (using inRange function). Blobs which contains only those 2 colors probably will be your informations (but unfortunetely some other things too - barcode, maybe some drawing or logo).
2 You regions should be rectangles, so if the blob is not rectangle - discard it.
3. If founded rectangle is rotated use affineTransform function to align it vertically - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358656/1598485) i've explained how to do it. Note that rectangle width and height should stay the same.
4. After using affine transform your rectangle might be rotated by 90, 180 or 270 degrees. In the example you provided on the top there is a black region - it it's true for all you images than finding top is quite easy - just find black rectangle within you region. In other case finding top might be harder - a quick idea, which might be worth testing is to look for black pixels in each white rectangle. In most cases there are aligned to center (not interesting case for us) or to the left - if you find left sied of rectangle, finding top is obvious :) Alternatively you may look for characters which are always on the right side - `%`, `g` and `mg`

If you will have any problems, give us more examples and describe what you have done already - right know it's hard to tell something more.